# como traer en una sola consulta todos los datos de una tabla y a la vez los las columnas y filas de las llaves foraneas?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de ver si puedo hacer todo en una sola query, ahora me explico mejor.

Tengo la tabla comentarios con sus campos hasta ahi esta bien me traigo todos los comentarios de un post y los campos de las referencias de las llaves foreaneas, hasta ahi voy bien.

Pasa que tengo otra tabla respuestas con el id del comentario y hasta ahora lo pude hacerlo solamente ejecutando las querys el el blucle donde recorro los resultados del array de comentarios osea para cada ciclo chekeo si ese comentario tiene respuestas en el bucle ya que necesito el id del comentario actual para saber si tiene respuestas. Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de implementar todo esto en una query para ahorrarme tener qeu estar haciendo consultas en el bucle. ahora les pongo algun codigo de ejemplo para qeu se entienda mejor.

```
<?php 
  $comentarios = pdo->prepare("SELECT comentaroios.id ...blabla WHERE post_id=:postid)");
   while($recorrer coentarios){echo "comentario['comentario']" blabla 
    $respuestas = pdo->prepare("SELECT respuesta.id.. blabla WHERE id_comentario=:id_comentario);
   while($respuestas){ mostrar respuestas}
   }
```

espero se entienda la idea basica de lo que estoy hacinedo y lo que quiero hacer.

si no quedo claro lo que quiero hacer es ahorrarme las consultas a la base de datos adetro del bucle.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, evita las formas coloquiales de referirse a las personas (no sabes quien lee, y si puede sentirse ofendido o no por como te referis a ellos). Hay un solo comentario por post? o muchos? si hubiera muchos, que queres traer?

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo lo que necesitás hacer es: traer tu listado de comentarios y sus respuestas

Viendo tu consulta lo que necesitas hacer es relacionar tus comentarios con tus repuesta por medio de tu llave foránea:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM comentarios C --(C es un alias que utilizarás en esa consulta para comentarios)
  --(left join es para traer siempre todos los comentarios que encuentres)
  --(inner join es para traer siempre todos los comentarios que encuentres)
  left join respuestas R --(R es un alias que utilizarás en esa consulta para respuestas)
  on C.id = R.id_comentario
  and c.post_id= :postid
```

Adicionalmente, te recomiendo que veas teoría de conjuntos enfocado a SQL, te comparto este [link](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DDimxwFXcAUe76q.jpg) para que lo estudiés.

Adicionalmente, te comento tus entidades o tablas, las estás nombrando en plural, la normalización de base de datos indica que se deben nombre de forma singular es decir, tus entidades debería de ser nombres como: **comentario** y **respuesta**

Comment: oh gracias si los tengo como llaves foreaneas pero no entiendo bien la consulta para relacionar las respuestas para los comentarios de cada post voy a ver que tal me va con tu respuestas gracias amigo